# How close to humans are agents?

Tags: the-matrix

During his fight with The Merovingian's henchmen, Neo blocks a sword with just his hand which seems to surprise everyone. However, a moment later his hand is cut causing The Merovingian to say

> "You see he's just **a man**"

(emphasis mine)

I always assumed this meant that only humans would bleed in The Matrix. This seems supported by the fact that no one else bleeds during the fight.

Later on, Morpheus cuts an Agent's face with his sword causing him to bleed. This got me thinking, are Agents close to humans in terms of their coding?

Comment: It looks like [this](http://alden-tan.com/wp-content/uploads/large-matrix-blu-ray7.jpg)... feel free to decipher it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't DV you but I can imagine it is because the answer is basically based on how agents appear : by taking human place

> Agents have the ability to take over the simulated body of any human that is a part of the Matrix, converting it into a copy of their own. If that body is killed, or an Agent needs to change its location quickly, it can assume the shell of any other human hard-wired to the Matrix in a matter of seconds. ([Wiki](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Agent))

They are just using **the same simulated body** that can bleed and be destroyed.